# Storing the result of a function in a variable used as input to the function

Tags: haskell

I am new to haskell and functional languages in general but i have some OO language background

Can someone show me the haskell equivalent of some code like this:

```
  int x = 5 

  x = doubleThis(x)

  function doubleThis(x){

  return x*x
  }
```

so if i had a function :

```
doubleThis :: Integer -> Integer
doubleThis x = x*x
```

how could i make it so that if i ran this:

```
let x = 5 
doubleThis x
output> 25
x
output> 25
```

my initial thought was that it would be something like:

```
let x = doubleThis x
```

but uh.... that seems to make an infinite loop

bonus points if you feel like showing me how to do this with concatenating a tuple onto a list

Comment: Haskell doesn't have variables like in Java or C.  Here you're defining `x` to be `doubleThis x` as a recursive definition.  This is perfectly acceptable in Haskell.  For example, you can define the fibonacci sequence as `let fibs = 1 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)`.  Or more simply you can define an empty list containing only 1s as `let ones = 1 : ones`.

Comment: so i would have to define it as let y = doubleThis x then let x = y?

Comment: No, you'd define it as `let y = doubleThis x` then use `y` instead of `x` and forget about ever "changing" the value of `x`.

Comment: @Blake Haskell doesn't have variables, and definitions can occur in any order. Once you define x to be something, that's what x will be (in that lexical scope). It won't change no matter how hard you try. There are some special rules in GHCi, but not in actual source code.

Comment: if the reason of trying to define `x <- f(x)` to find f(f(x)), f(f(f(x))), etc instead use `iterate doubleThis 5`

Comment: This is too broad man. You need to just start reading a book or tutorial.

Comment: In Haskell, everything is immutable. Once `x` was defined, if will keep that value forever. To an imperative programmer, this might look as extremely constraining, and possibly preventing any programming at all. In practice, this is not the case, since pure FP has been used for virtually any task successfully (also because, there are some libraries that model mutation like `ST`, but they are mostly unneeded). If you need to "mutate" `x`, you probably need some recursion like `f x = if x == then 2 else f (newValue x)` -- this is how looping works in Haskell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int x = 5

x = doubleThis(x)

function doubleThis(x){return x*x}
```

You seem to have figured out how to do the last line. And the first line.

What you *cannot* do is the middle line. Haskell purposely does not allow this. What you *can* do is

```
x1 = 5

x2 = doubleThis x1
```

That's perfectly fine. But you can't *change* the value of an existing variable. This is a deliberate design choice.

Don't try to think in terms of "I have this imperative code, how do I write something in Haskell that does exactly the same thing?" The whole *point* of Haskell is that you do things a completely different way. Rather, think "What problem am I actually trying to solve? What would be the most sensible way to do that in Haskell?"

Comment: There are no variables in Haskell.

Comment: @GeorgJohannSchubert Well, the `x` in `f x = x^2` is usually called a variable, even if its value is immutable. This convention follows maths, where in `f(x)=x^2` the `x` is called a variable as well. It "varies" in the sense that you can call `f` on several distinct arguments, both in maths and Haskell.